# Add two business days to a date array excluding holiday dates

Tags: php, date

I am trying to add 2 weekdays to a date, but I also want to exclude the days in an array.

array of dates to exclude:

```
$bankHolidays = array();
foreach($obj as $e) {
    if($e->division == 'england-and-wales') {
        foreach($e->events as $events) {
            $bankHolidays[] = $events->date;
        }
    }
}
```

Adding 2 working days to date

```
$ret = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($bill["charge_customer_at"]. ' +2 weekdays'));
```

How can I include the array of dates to exclude?

As an example, if my date was `2017-07-19` and i want to add 2 week days, that would output `2017-07-21`.

But if `2017-07-21` was in my array, it should skip this date and continue adding 2 weekdays so the output would end up being `2017-07-24` because of the weekend as well.

Comment: I've read through your question a couple times and don't understand your desired output. I'm pretty sure I could do this if you give an example of your desired output.

Comment: check my update, i have provided an example. i hope it makes sense

Comment: Have your script return the date + 2 days.

Do a "holiday check", see if that new date exists in your holiday array. If it does, then add a day to it.

Then you just need to validate if its a weekday. If the day generated is a Saturday or Sunday, then add 1 day to the date, and rerun the whole thing (starting with holiday check).

Sounds like you have it in theory already? Just use the `in_array()` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something as simple as use a `while` loop.

```
$date = '2017-07-25';
$reserved = ['2017-07-27', '2017-07-28'];
$days = 2;

while ($days > 0) {
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' +1 weekday'));
    if (! in_array($date, $reserved)) $days--;
}

var_dump($date);
```

Comment: This solution is adding `+1 day` when the OP wants to add weekdays

Comment: Good spot. Fixed.

Comment: Wow. I would never have thought to do it like that. +1 just for the unorthodoxy of it, never mind how fast you came up with it.

Comment: @AuntJamaima - why do you say it's unorthodox?

Comment: I think of traditional counting as counting up instead of down. I like your solution.

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is for you, but there is a lib for checking holidays for concrete locales: [heiglandreas/holidayChecker](https://github.com/heiglandreas/holidayChecker). It will allow you to check if the selected business days is not a public holiday somehow.

Comment: Nice solution with easter can be found here: https://gist.github.com/massiws/9593008

Answer (score 2):

**Find the next business day function with a given offset.**

The following basically takes your given date, the number of days you want to skip, in your case 2, and the holidays array that you prepopulate as you show in your question. If the weekday that's so many after your date is a holiday it adds a day and checks again.

```
function nextBusinessDay($date, $daysToSkip,$holidays){
    $day = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date. ' + '.$daysToSkip.' weekday'));
    if(!in_array($day,$holidays)){
         return $day;
    } else {
        return nextBusinessDay(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.' +1 day')), $daysToSkip,$holidays);
    }
}

$date = '2017-07-19';
$holidays = ['2017-07-21'];
echo nextBusinessDay($date,2,$holidays);//returns 2017-07-24

$date = '2017-07-19';
$holidays = ['2017-07-21', '2017-07-24'];
echo nextBusinessDay($date,2,$holidays);//returns 2017-07-25 like if it were a 4 day weekend
```

Sorry it took me a while to get a chance to look it over and post something. This should work for you. My understanding is that you need to return the first business date that is two days from a given date, not keep adding two week days until the date isn't in your holidays array. If you really want to keep adding 2 days, or however many days, then change

```
return nextBusinessDay(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.' +1 day')), $daysToSkip,$holidays);
```

to

```
return nextBusinessDay(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.' +'.$daysToSkip.' day')), $daysToSkip,$holidays);
```

Comment: Thanks for putting this together - it seems to return the correct dates but i am actually running this inside another function and I think its causing a problem returning values inside 2 functions - could this cause an issue?

Comment: What's your second function? Return simply means that the value of the function is whatever is in the return. You can nest as many functions as you want. Show me what you have and I can show you how to make it work.